# WP newbie: using else/if statements to show multiple headers. bonks

Tags: conditional-tags

This code is fine but if I try to copy the last 3 lines and add a new custom page with a new custom header class, it doesn't work. I just want to add 2 new pages to my WP site with different headers from the front page and the rest of the site (which is set to use wrapper8 for the rest of the site pages which don't have specific headers). *see: www.friendsofnamibianchildren.org* Instead, very annoying, it applies wrapper8 to any new pages I add, thus applying the wrong template.

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) {?>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="wrapper8">
<?php }?>
<?php if (is_page('About Us')) {?>
<div class="wrapper2">
<?php }?>
<?php if (is_page('Our Work')) {?>
<div class="wrapper3">
<?php }?>
<?php if (is_page('Get Involved')) {?>
<div class="wrapper4">
<?php }?>
<?php if (is_page('About Namibia')) {?>
<div class="wrapper5">
<?php }?>
<?php if (is_page('Donate')) {?>
<div class="wrapper6">
<?php }?>
<?php if (is_page('Photos')) {?>
<div class="wrapper7">
<?php }?>
```

If try to add these 3 lines below (basically a new Sitemap page with a 'wrapper9' header) then all the site templates get messed up.

```
<?php if (is_page('Sitemap')) {?>
<div class="wrapper9">
<?php }?>
```

thanks.

Comment: have you created the page with the title Sitemap? There should not be any spelling mistakes.

Comment: the page file I was trying to add was called Sitemap.php and the reference to it was 'Sitemap' in the code. It was appearing in the template dropdown but instead of applying this new template's class of 'wrapper9', the statement would apply the 'wrapper8' tag instead. I double-checked references to make sure the spelling was correct but am not a developer so I could have missed something. thank you!

Comment: go to the admin, click all pages link under the pages section, check if you have a page named Sitemap or not. If not, then create one. This code should be working if there is a page with the title 'Sitemap'

Comment: Thank you - the problem was that I had named the page 'Site Map' for the title, not 'Sitemap' as referenced in the template name and in the php code. Thanks so much. All fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Your site seems to be not having a page named Sitemap. When I am saying this, it does mean to check your code, just check your site's dashboard. 
Under the Pages section, click All Pages link. This will show you all pages of your site. There you can see if you have a page with titled 'Sitemap' or not. If not, then create one and specify it's title as 'Sitemap' (without quotes).
I am sure, you will get the results.

Comment: say thanks by selecting my answer and up-voting (if you like it)

Comment: @awesome: my pleasure :P

Answer (score 0):

It's applying wrapper8 to any new page because it isn't the front page as per the first if/else statement. You'd need to join them all together into one string of if/else statements.

This code here cleans things up a bit (if it wasn't so late, I'd try to get it down to just one array):

```
<?php 
    $pages = array('About Us','Our Work', 'Get Involved', 'About Namibia', 'Donate', 'Photos', 'Sitemap');
    $wrappers = array(
        'About Us'      =>  'wrapper2',
        'Our Work'      =>  'wrapper3',
        'Get Involved'  =>  'wrapper4',
        'About Namibia' =>  'wrapper5',
        'Donate'        =>  'wrapper6',
        'Photos'        =>  'wrapper7',
        'Sitemap'       =>  'wrapper9'
    );
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $wrap = 'wrapper';
    } elseif (is_page($pages)) {
        $wrap = $wrappers[get_the_title()];
    } else {
        $wrap = 'wrapper8';
    }
?>
    <div class="<?php echo $wrap; ?>">
```

Comment: I will try this in the header.php file where the original code was, thank you so much!!!

Comment: totally bizarro your code kept everything the same, the wrapper 8 is still being applied - so this points to something else being the issue then perhaps? I cleared the cache too. ugh

Comment: This code only cleans things up and does not answer his query

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes with Wordpress I've had issues applying something through is_page().
The workaround I always do is to use the_permalink() in my IF conditions instead.
Admittedly it's not the best thing if you want re-usable code, but on another project it's only another couple of minutes to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create unique classes for styling on each page. Rather than going through all of this work (and having to update your theme for each new page which is unsustainable in the long run), look into the [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function. You use it like this:

```
<body <?php echo body_class(); ?>>
```

As the codex article shows, it gives you a ton of classes to work with. Better yet, if you need to add on more, you can just pass the function an argument which you might dynamically define beforehand:

```
<body <?php echo body_class( $my_custom_class ); ?>>
```